# Control displayed with an offset in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mfc, win32gui

Recently I have migrated my source code from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013.

After building in Visual Studio 2013, controls are displayed with an offset (see image by clicking on the link below).

**[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo6VR.jpg)**

Does anybody know what happens?

Comment: Have you also changed the dotnet framework version?

Comment: VS2013 Dotnet Frame Work 4.5.51650 VS2010 Dotnet Framework 4.0.30319

Comment: Can you try to build the VS2013 solution for 4.0 framework version?

Comment: Can you show some images ? One with from build from vs2010 the other from the build with vs2013.

Comment: @bdn02 it's an MFC project, so dotnet shouldn't matter, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes Thats Correct its MFC project so I also believe Dot Net Framework should not matter here

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by `symmetry`. Are talking about alignment? Could you please demo it with an image (actual and expected)? I suspect that the reason is not the version of Visual Studio, but the changes in, for example, DPI settings. Are your controls positioned by Resource Editor, or do you manually move windows around?

Comment: trying to upload image but not able to do so. By Symmetry I mean that Buttons or group box edges are getting merged in to the window frame edges

Comment: @WENzER you can upload an image to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/).

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/2w4y8 Uploaded the image of both version.

Comment: as you can see in image, static box is getting merged in to frame which is win32 control. same thing is happenning for other screen so if buttons or slide control are at bottom of the window they are also getting merge with the frame and are not showing properly

Comment: So - do you move/resize the windows in that dialog at runtime? Could you please share that code?

Comment: Windows are fixed size but are movable and even if am moving the window screen remains same(distorted). Not sure what code you want to see?

Comment: The code is same nothing changed from VS2010 it is working fine with VS2010. But the same code when am building on VS2013 the WIN32 controls are getting clipped as shown in images. I thought it may be related to DPI settings so when I changed the DPI settings of my monitor to 125 it looked better but not as VS2010. Then I build the code by changing VS2013 Project Manifest Property to High DPI Aware but that also did not work.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  Isn't the same issue discussed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772651/dialog-border-different-after-porting-code-from-visual-studio-6-to-visual-studio?lq=1

Comment: @WENzER yes, it's probably the same or at least a similar issue. Try to compile your program with one of the "_xp" toolsets. Right click on your project in the Solution Explorer, then under Configuration Properties->General set the platform toolset to "Visual Studio 2013 (v120_xp)" (or at least one whiththe "_xp" suffix and try again.

Comment: Thanks a zillion @MichaelWalz, your solution worked for me as well :)

Comment: @WENzER happy to see that it works for you, but still there is clearly a problem with your code, it should work on any platform (which is the case with my code). My crystal ball tells me you should have a look at the [AdjustWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632665(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think issue was with the border frame thickness of dialog box. I changed the following property in project settings & that worked for me.
 Project Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Platefortoolset, set it to Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp) And it worked. Thanks everyone for help