# Dialog border different after porting code from Visual Studio 6 to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I have just ported a dialog based MFC program from Visual Studio 6 to to Visual Studio 2013. There were no major issues and the program runs perfectly once compiled under VS 2013.

The only visible difference is the thickness of the dialog's borders (see screen shots below made under Windows 7).

[image]

More facts:

- It's not a manifest issue, both manifests in the old and new versions are strictly the same.
- The .rc hasn't been messed up during the conversion of the project by VS2012. If I compile the converted project again with VS6 I get thin borders.
- I can reproduce the issue with a freshly wizard generated program in Visual Studio 6.
- A message box shown with `AfxMessageBox` also has a thin border when compiled with VS6 and a thick border when compiled
  with VS2013.

Comment: In newer versions of Windows, the system parameter for the border thickness was broken into two parts. The upward compatibility of this change was poorly considered on Microsoft's part. It's likely that VS2013 compensates properly for the change while VS6 does not.

Comment: @MarkRansom could you be more specific about that border thinkness thing you were writing about? Even a message box displayed with a raw `::MessageBox` exhibits this difference in behaviour; it's like there was some application wide setting being applied somehow- There is [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768621/win32-control-distortion-in-visual-studio-2013) dealing with a similar problem.

Comment: The parameter I'm thinking of is `SM_CXPADDEDBORDER`, which didn't exist when VS6 came out. I don't have any more information than that right now, sorry - if I did I'd leave an answer. If it helps, I think the VS6 borders are too thin and the VS2013 borders are correct.

Comment: @MarkRansom just googled "SM_CXPADDEDBORDER" and the first results show many "problem"s and "incorrect"s, looks as if this is the right lead. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I remember we have experienced similar issue and that time it was related with subsystem flags of PE header or like that. Would you mind to drop an output of dumpbin /A of both binaries (especially "operating system version" and "subsystem version" value)? If they differ, that's the reason, I'll write more detailed answer.

Comment: @ArtemRazin you are right, with subsystem version 6.0 I get the the thick borders and with subsystem 4.0 I get the thin borders. If you make this an answer I'll accept it and yo'll get an upvote from me and my work mates.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I think it is the same issue which am discussing here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768621/control-displayed-with-an-offset-in-visual-studio-2013, Please let me know if you have solution of this

Comment: If your application has a subsystem version less than 6.0 (as set by the linker), then the operating system will lie to it (for backwards compatibility reasons, since `SM_CXPADDEDBORDER` was added to Vista) about the size of the window's border padding. If the subsystem version is >= 6.0, then you get the real information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced similar issue and it was related with subsystem flag of PE header.

I needed to debug Windows a bit to find the reason: the function `win32k!_GetWindowBorders` checks that PE flag against 6.0 (probably to support new flag `SM_CXPADDEDBORDER`).

See also:

- [Regression: ::GetSystemMetrics delivers different values](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753224)