# Buttons on Dialog align differently in release and debug mode in MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

My dialog with OK and Cancel buttons looks good in Debug mode and as designed in designer, but in release mode the margins set in the designer are not honored and the buttons simply sit right on the bottom edge of a dialog.

Any ideas how to fix that issue so it looks identical in debug and release mode?

I know I could simply make them look good in release mode but the whole point is that debug mode is where I work most with and I'd like to see how it will look in release mode.

**Debug mode:**

[image]

**Release mode:**

[image]

Comment: I'd also add any pertinent code that deals with the buttons.  Have you made any recent changes to the button locations?

Comment: Either the RC file has gotten messed up and your margins have disappeared (that happens to me sometimes), or you have conditional code in your application that causes differential execution in debug or release mode. Obviously you'd know to look for such an `#ifdef` statement, right? Another possibility is a manifest that is causing the OS to report its border widths differently. Does the release mode link in a manifest indicating Windows v6.0+ compatibility, while the debug mode doesn't, or vice versa?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768621/control-displayed-with-an-offset-in-visual-studio-2013) and at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772651/dialog-border-different-after-porting-code-from-visual-studio-6-to-visual-studio) SO questions which deal with similar issues.